# Port iOS GPUImageBilateralFilter to Android

Tags: android, ios, gpuimage

I developed iOS app using GPUImage including GPUImageBilateralFilter.
Now I am going to port the iOS app to Android, but I've found there is no GPUImageBilateralFilter in Android GPUImage library.
How can I port this filter in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do have the entire source code for that filter [right here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageBilateralFilter.m). I talk a little more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456202/how-do-i-blur-a-uiimage-but-preserve-sharp-object-boundaries/14488905#14488905) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817630/are-the-gpuimagebilateralfilter-parameters-of-the-gpuimage-ios-library-the-equiv/20821578#20821578), but it's a relatively simple bilateral blur. It uses a hardcoded set of 9 Gaussian samples about a central pixel, split into horizontal and vertical passes.

All you need to do is take the vertex and fragment shaders from the GPUImage repository and write your own implementation of a two-pass filter that does this within whatever Android framework you're using. If they've already got a separated Gaussian blur, that shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Thanks. let me check the links. btw I am still curious why there is no GPUImageBilateralFilter in Android. can you let me know why it does?

Comment: @ttotto - I don't know. I have nothing to do with any of the attempted ports of this to Android (I don't do any Android development myself), and I think the two I've seen only got a small fraction of the framework ported over before they stopped.